# How to compare two arrays keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays where the first array keys are similar to second array values. I'd like to get a new array with values which are not in the first one. I tried to use `array_intersect`, but the result wasn't what I expected.

Here is a sample of the two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
    'A' => 10,
    'B' => 20,
    'C' => 30,
    'D' => 40,
);
$array2 = array(
    '0' => 'A',
    '1' => 'B',
);
```

And I'm looking for a new array like this:

```
$array3 = array(
    '0' => 'C',
    '1' => 'D',
);
```

Comment: `array_keys(array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$array1 = array('A' => 10,'B' => 20,'C' => 30,'D' => 40);
$array2 = array('0' => 'A','1' => 'B');
$array3 = array_keys(array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2)));
```

Comment: what is the structure of new array if $array2 is empty

Comment: You should check firstly if $array2 is not empty: if(!empty($array2)){...} or if(count($array2)){...}

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use `array_diff`, but the problem is that it is not setting keys

```
$array3 = array_diff(array_keys($array1, $array2))
```